# Execute jar command with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I need to run

```
jar -cvf myapp.war *
```

command with Maven build, I have a project 'myapp'. At present I have some shell script to build the war file.

```
cd /something/myapp
jar -cvf myapp.war *
```

It generates myapp.war file, no concern of web app folder structure (it already in web app folder structure).

I want to do with Maven pom instead of shell script, but I want to run the same command with Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look to this maven plugin :

http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
```

It allows you to execute system and Java programs during your build lifecycle.

According your needs, you may use exec:java goal.

You could also implement a simple Maven plugin (Mojo class) that calls the required method from your jar.

Answer (score 1):

Change your project's `<packaging>` to `war` and use the `maven-war-plugin`. Maven has different plugins for different packaging types. You can also try the `maven-assembly-plugin`, if you're planning on producing several artifacts from one project.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution:

1. Don't specify `\<packaging\>\</packaging\>` for this pom.
2. Add below code and remove any maven-war or maven-jar plugins if already defined in `<plugins>`.

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>export_objects</id>
                       <phase>install</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>exec</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                   <executable>jar</executable>
                   <commandlineArgs> -cvf myapp.war *</commandlineArgs>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```